# php regexp: can't exclude one element

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to set-up a quite complex regexp, but I can't avoid just one element from not-match list.

My regular expression is:

```
1234567-8_abc((?!_ABC|_DEFGHI)[\w]?)*(\.ios|\.and)
```

What I have to exclude is:

- **1234567-8_abc.ios**
- 1234567-8_abc_DEFGHI.ios
- 1234567-8_abc_ABC.ios

Instead, what I have to include is:

- 1234567-8_abc_1UP.ios
- 1234567-8_abc_FI.ios
- 1234567-8_abc_gmg.ios
- 1234567-8_abc_1UP.and
- 1234567-8_abc_FI.and
- 1234567-8_abc_gmg.and
- 1234567-8_abc_ddd.and
- 1234567-8_abc_qwert.ios
- 1234567-8_abc_88.ios

Well, I can't exclude the first option (**1234567-8_abc.ios**).

I tried it [here](http://regex101.com/).

How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex matches your examples in PHP:

```
1234567-8_abc_((?!ABC|DEFGHI)[\w]?)*(\.ios|\.and)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```
1234567-8_abc_[^_.]++(?<!_ABC|_DEFGHI)\.(?:ios|and)
```

Note: I assume that each substring between `_` and `.ios` doesn't contain a dot or an underscore.

The [possessive quantifier](http://regular-expressions.com/possessive.html) `++` is necessary to fail faster with the less possible backtracking steps

Answer (score 0):

Add a negative lookahead like below,

```
1234567-8_abc(?!_ABC|_DEFGHI)\w+(\.ios|\.and)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/tF4jD3/14)

`(?!_ABC|_DEFGHI)` Negative lookahead asserts that the string following `_abc` wouldn't be `_ABC` or `_DEFGHI` . And it must have one or more word characters before `.ios` or `.and`. So it won't match this `1234567-8_abc.ios` string.

Answer (score 0):

```
1234567-8_abc(?:(?!_ABC|_DEFGHI)\w)+(\.ios|\.and)
```

Try this.Your regex has left `\w` after `1234567-8_abc` optional.Just made it compulsary.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/bB8jY7/1

Comment: Just a minor note: `[\w]` can be just `\w`.